# How to make repeated requests for tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-multiprocessing

I want to make repeated requests to a server that will return with some tasks. The response from the server will be a dictionary with a list of functions that need to be called. For example:

```
{ 
   tasks: [
      {
         function: "HelloWorld",
         id: 1212
      },
      {
         function: "GoodbyeWorld"
         id: 1222
      }
   ]
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm dummying it down.

For each of these tasks, I will run the specified function using `multiprocessing`. Here is an example of my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://localhost:5000', auth=('user', 'pass'))
data = r.json()

if len(data["tasks"]) > 0:
  manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
  for task in data["tasks"]:
    if task["function"] == "HelloWorld":
      helloObj = HelloWorldClass()
      hello = multiprocessing.Process(target=helloObj.helloWorld)
      hello.start()
      hello.join()
    elif task["function"] == "GoodbyeWorld":
      byeObj = GoodbyeWorldClass()
      bye = multiprocessing.Process(target=byeObj.byeWorld)
      bye.start()
      bye.join()
```

The problem is, I want to make repeated requests and fill the `data["tasks"]` array as the other processes are running. If I throw everything into some `while` loop, it'll only make a request after all the processes from the initial response is done (when `join()` has been reached for all processes).

Can anyone help me to make repeated requests and fill the array continuously?  Please let me know if I need to make any clarifications.

Comment: Looks like what you need instead is a queue. First you drop all your response results to one of those https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html, then pop items in queue one by one and start processing until finished. HTTP responses will not interfere with the queue like they do with arrays and code will be a bit easier to reason about.

Comment: @jim have you considered use of asyncio or Celery? Or that is not an option for you?

Comment: so basically you call `start()` and right after you wait for this thread to end with `join()`. You should make some list of `threads=[]` then add it when created `threads += [hello]` same for bye. Do join at the end `for th in threads: th.join()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

import requests

from task import FunctionFactory


def get_tasks():
    resp = requests.get('https://localhost:5000', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    data = resp.json()

    return data['tasks']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = {}

    for _ in range(10):
        tasks = get_tasks()

        if not tasks:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue

        for task in tasks:

            if task['id'] in procs:
                # This task has been already submitted for execution.
                continue

            func = FunctionFactory.build(task['function'])

            proc = Process(target=func)
            proc.start()

            procs[task['id']] = proc

    # Waiting for all the submitted tasks to finish.
    for proc in procs.values():
        proc.join()
```

Here, the function `get_tasks` is used to request a list of dictionaries with `id` and `function` keys from the server. In the main section, there is a `procs` dictionary that maps `id` to running process instances which execute functions built by a `FunctionFactory` using received tasks' `function` names. In the case there is already a running task with the same id, it gets ignored.

With this approach, you can request tasks as often as needed (here, `10` requests are used in a `for` loop) and start processes to execute them in parallel. In the end, you just wait for all the submitted tasks to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your program, you should call the `join`s **after** you've created **all the tasks**. Join blocks until the process has finished -- in your case before you start the next one. Which practically makes you whole program run sequentially.